# How to validate array using foreach loop?

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, validation, foreach

I have this **working code** used for validating my color options.

```
 if ( !function_exists( 'sanitize_hex_color' ) ) {
     function sanitize_hex_color($color) {
        if ( '' === $color )
     return '';

  // 3 or 6 hex digits, or the empty string.
  if ( preg_match('|^#([A-Fa-f0-9]{3}){1,2}$|', $color ) )
    return $color;

  return null;
  }
}

function validate_color_option($options){
//Check if hex color and sanitize
$options['wrapper_background_color'] = sanitize_hex_color($options['wrapper_background_color']);
$options['display_bg'] = sanitize_hex_color($options['display_bg']);

//Strips all html from input type text (NOT a color field)
$options['big_heading'] = wp_strip_all_tags($options['big_heading']);

return $options;

}//Function end
```

But since i will have a lot of color field's I would like to store my colors into an array do a foreach loop and validate my color options via **sanitize_hex_color** function. Something like this:

```
if ( !function_exists( 'sanitize_hex_color' ) ) {
     function sanitize_hex_color($color) {
        if ( '' === $color )
     return '';

  // 3 or 6 hex digits, or the empty string.
  if ( preg_match('|^#([A-Fa-f0-9]{3}){1,2}$|', $color ) )
    return $color;

  return null;
  }
}

function validate_color_option($options){
  $colors = array(
  'color1' => $options['wrapper_background_color'],
  'color2' => $options['display_bg']
  );

   foreach($colors as $key => $val) {
   $colors[$key] = sanitize_hex_color($val);
   }

   //Strips all html from input type text (NOT a color field)
   $options['big_heading'] = wp_strip_all_tags($options['big_heading']);

   return $options;

}//Function end
```

To be honest I have no idea how to do validation using foreach loop and then return my values back:( Can you guys help me? Thank you!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`array_map()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php)

```
$colors = array(<colors>);
array_map("sanitize_hex_color", $colors);
```

It should return an array of results for each color. 
Then you process it further somehow.